# Spring @Import annotation isn't working as expected

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm developing a multi-module project using Spring Boot 2.0.5.RELEASE, Java 8. It consists of model, DAO, and various microservices. Usage of DAO beans is provided by the @Import annotation, as listed below:

**Microservice:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableDao
public class Application {

    public static ConfigurableApplicationContext CONTEXT;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CONTEXT = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

**DAO:**

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Import(DaoConfiguration.class)
public @interface EnableDao {
/* empty */
}
```

```
@Configuration
@EntityScan("blah.blah.blah.dao")
@EnableJpaRepositories("blah.blah.blah.dao.repo")
public class DaoConfiguration {
/* Some tricks with EntityManager also */
}
```

```
@Repository
public interface SomethingRepo extends JpaRepository<Something, Long> {
/* + some default methods */
}
```

But I've got running the code:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'blah.blah.blah.dao.repo.SomethingRepo' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Why the hell my code doesn't create the bean? What can be the cause?

Comment: Does it work if you add `@Import(DaoConfiguration.class)` directly to the `Application` ?

Comment: It didn't, but adding ```@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = {SomethingRepo.class})``` was a working solution.

Comment: Have same problem. When using custom Entity/Repository scanner the `@SpringBootApplication` then don't want scan `Entities` and `Repositories` in its location package. And I have to explicitly add `@EntityScan` and `@EnableJpaRepositories` in my `Application` class.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Still don't know why it has such behaviour, but I found the solution adding annotation 
`@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = {SomethingRepo.class})`
to the `Application.class`

Comment: Don't mark it as solved. It is not good solution a think, we need people to find this question and help an least explain why this happens.